# Understanding output stepAIC

Tags: data-mining, r, feature-selection

I am using the `stepAIC` function in R to do a bi-directional (forward and backward) stepwise regression. I do not understand what each return value from the function means.

The output is:

```
          Df     Sum of Sq    RSS       AIC
<none>                        350.71   -5406.0
- aaa      1     0.283        350.99   -5405.9
- bbb      1     0.339        351.05   -5405.4
- ccc      1     0.982        351.69   -5400.5
- ddd      1     0.989        351.70   -5400.5
```

Question Are the values listed under `Df`, `Sum of Sq`, `RSS`, and `AIC` the values for a model where only one variable would be considered as the independent variable (i.e. y ~
aaa, y ~ bbb, etc.)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a simple R programming question and should be on http://stackoverflow.com or http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As R is a primary data science tool, I don't find this off topic IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with someone I found out that the <none> corresponds to a model that would include all the variables, in other words none of the variables were removed. So consider the line in the output for the variable aaa. The listed RSS and AIC are the values for a model that would include all variables but aaa and we see an increase in the RSS and AIC. The other listed results can be considered in the same fashion. The best model is then the one where none are removed since this has the smallest AIC.